# SQL Get the 10 biggest numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to retrive the 10 biggest numbers from a table called bonus.

But I'm getting this error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'
```

My code:

```
SELECT cust_nr, period1_bonus FROM bonus ORDER BY period1_bonus DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is not a ANSI compatible SQL keyword - it's used in MySQL, but most other RDBMS use the ANSI  `SELECT TOP (x) ... ` syntax instead

Comment: @marc_s: "most" is `SQL Server` and `Sybase`? `TOP` is not `ANSI` too: `ANSI` is `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` which is only supported by `DB2` and `PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is also tagged w/ c#, I'm assuming you're also interested in executing this in c#.  Here is the linq-to-sql equivalent of the SQL code.

```
public IEnumerable<Bonus> GetHighestValues()
{
    var query = (from b in _context.bonus
                 take 10                     
                 orderby b.period1_bonus descending
                 select b);
    return query;
}
```

Edit - I see that the c# tag has now been removed from the question.  Still, my answer might help you (or others).

Answer (score 8):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT TOP 10 cust_nr, period1_bonus FROM bonus ORDER BY period1_bonus DESC
```

`LIMIT <x>` is a mySQL construct, not an MSSQL construct. `TOP` should work for you here.

Comment: The `LIMIT <x>` is not part of my query.

Comment: @dumbel, how is that possible? The word LIMIT is not even in the statement.

Comment: Fixed it now just rermoved limit and worked. Thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 6):

Try **SELECT TOP**

```
SELECT TOP 10 cust_nr, period1_bonus 
FROM bonus 
ORDER BY period1_bonus DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure, but will

```
SELECT TOP 10 cust_nr, period1_bonus FROM bonus ORDER BY period1_bonus DESC
```

be working?

Edit: lol, I think i was right (now seeing the other answers suddenly) +1 for @Martin for asking for the rdbms:)

Comment: Thank you, not the 10 biggest numbers. but it seems its just printing the first 10 numbers

Comment: Yes, you sort your result from the biggest value down to the lowest and just return the first ten results. Isn't that what you were searching for?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using `SQL Server`.

In `TSQL`, the syntax is this:

```
SELECT  TOP 10 cust_nr, period1_bonus
FROM    bonus
ORDER BY
        period1_bonus DESC
```